# Scraping dynamic content in a website

Tags: python, perl, web-scraping

I need to scrape news announcements from this website, [Link](http://www.marketvectorsindices.com/#!News/List).
The announcements seem to be generated dynamically. They dont appear in the source. I usually use mechanize but I assume it wouldnt work. What can I do for this? I'm ok with python or perl.

Comment: In Perl, `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` might work (if the page works in Firefox).

Comment: You can refer to the last answer in this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323728/scraping-dynamic-content-in-a-website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polite option would be to ask the owners of the site if they have an API which allows you access to their news stories.

The less polite option would be to trace the HTTP transactions that take place while the page is loading and work out which one is the AJAX call which pulls in the data.

Looks like it's [this one](http://www.marketvectorsindices.com/cms/?_t=c485b0b8706268b3bcfde2c989d81ca4&p=1&c=100). But it looks like it might contain session data, so I don't know how long it will continue to work for.

Comment: How did you identify the file?

Comment: Probably firebug or the new web-console in firefox 8.. or similar.

Comment: I'm old-skool. I used the HTTP Live Headers extension for Firefox.

Comment: @ØyvindSkaar I have firebug, could you tell me how to look for it?

Comment: @Aks Don't have it installed, but there's "Net" tab or something that can show you all the GET (and POST etc) requests the browser does when loading the page. This includes the ones made by the javascript code. Those probably appear far down. As you use the site, you can see what ajax calls (just GET's, POST's etc) are made. See http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: ok. thanks. btw, will the _t parameter change or can I use it as a link?

Comment: No-one can possibly know what the _t parameter is. As I implied above, it might be some kind of session information. I suppose you might get a clue if you examined the Javascript that makes the request. Or, the best solution is probably to ask the site owners to explain the parameters to their AJAX API. You *really* shouldn't just use it without talking to them first.

Answer (score 11):

If the content is generated dynamically, you can use `Windmill` or `Seleninum` to drive the browser and get the data once it's been rendered.

You can find an example [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/web-scraping-with-python-part-2).

Answer (score 0):

There's also [WWW::Scripter](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aScripter) "For scripting web sites that have scripts" . Never used it.

Answer (score -8):

In python you can use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and [urllib2](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml) to connect to a website and collect data.  For example:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
myUrl = "http://www.marketvectorsindices.com/#!News/List"
inStream = urlopen(myUrl)
instream.read(1024) # etc, in a while loop
# all your fun page parsing code (perhaps: import from xml.dom.minidom import parse)
```

Comment: Does this handle javascript and similar client-side stuff?

Comment: Nope.  You're better off with jcollado's answer, looking at Windmill or Selenium if you're on python.  Haven't used them though.