# Python Mechanize can't find login.live.com form

Tags: python, html, mechanize-python

I'm trying to login to a login.live.com, but Mechanize will not recognize that there is a form on that page. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.open('https://login.live.com/')
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

This results in:

> mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0

When there clearly is a form on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting the form by name instead with `br.select_form(name="f1")`.

(I got the form name from the page source - I assume you want the login form.)

Comment: Sorry, I just installed mechanize and tried this. Didn't work :/.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the form is not in the html that is delivered as a response to the HTTP GET request. It's being created later a a result of a javascript script being executed in the browser.

For more information about how to get content that has been dynamically generated, please have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8323728/183066).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like I can pass paramaters using urllib and urllib2 properly. If I can figure out how to enable cookies...

Answer (score 1):

```
r = br.open('https://login.live.com/')
r.get_data()
# outputs:
# ...
# Windows Live ID requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being blocked
# ...
```

I found no workaround, and am suggesting you to use Selenium/webdriver instead.