# How can you use Python to fill out HTML forms that also have Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, mechanize

I am making a python program that automatically enters information into a form on a website. I looked at a module called mechanize at first but then I realized that it didn't support javascript. Is there any way to take a piece of information and insert it into a "form" on a website that uses javascript?

The website I am using is www.locationary.com.

If you login and then go to a place/business page like this,

http://www.locationary.com/place/en/US/California/Los_Angeles/Z_Pizza-p1001157911.jsp

then you will see a bunch of spots that need to be filled in. I looked at the page source and this "form" uses javascript. I just need a way to fill in those blanks now. Like I said, I tried mechanize and it didn't work but I also googled it and got nothing.

The "form" uses "onclick"

If you could offer any advice, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: To really do this you need an environment that makes the page think it's really in a web browser. Generally that's sufficiently hard that people go the route of harnessing an actual browser somehow.

Comment: I just found something called Selenium..would it work?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editInfo(&quot;xxx_c_1_f_983&quot; ,false)">Add This (+4 Shares, +300 Tickets)</a>

Comment: @S.Lott yes, it is using onclick i guess

Comment: Please **update** the question with all the facts.  Do not add comments to the question.  Please **update** the question and then delete the comments.

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8323728/183066).

Answer (score 1):

I think probably the best way to do this is to use a framework that can operate through a browser.  There are several options, but the most pythonic is windmill http://www.getwindmill.com/

I've found it useful on a number of projects.