# why is mechanize not downloading the full page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am using Mechanize to sign into LinkedIn and get all the employees of a certain company.
However when I download the page with the search results of the employees it is missing the whole middle and I have no idea why.

Here is my code (took out my linkedin sign in info):

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
br=Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open('https://www.linkedin.com/')
br.select_form('login')
br['session_key']=YOUR_EMAIL_HERE
br['session_password']=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE
response=br.submit()
page=br.open('https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=10667')
html=page.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
text=soup.prettify()
text=text.encode("ascii", "ignore")
fo= open("website.html",'wb')
fo.write(text)
fo.close()
```

The response is this (I recommend downloading the HTML and just looking at it with a browser): http://pastebin.com/7z1dPiTd

I am not sure if I used the open function correctly, that may be the problem.

Comment: You'd better use [`linkedin api`](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis) instead.

Comment: I have looked into it, they do not provide any way to get the employees of a company

Comment: Is that data provided by AJAX ? If so, mechanize is not going to see it.

Comment: @dilbert I believe it is just HTML

Answer (score 0):

Alright, 
After doing some research it seems that Mechanize was not waiting for the Javascript to load and therefore I was not downloading the correct info.
Mechanize does not provide a method for waiting for the Javascript, so I have to use either windmill or selenium 
look at these:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323728/scraping-dynamic-content-in-a-website)
and 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833239/how-to-make-mechanize-wait-for-web-page-full-load)