# Urllib2 not reading all html on page

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to simple retireive the html of a page (its a work thing so unfortunately I'm unable to provide the link), however only a part of the html is returned. Other pages on this site seem to work as expected.

I understand that urllib2 does not handle javascript ([urllib2 not returning full webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516933/urllib2-not-returning-full-webpage)), but when I disable javascript in my Firefox browser the page loads up correctly.

I then tried @Jed Smith's and @John Weldon's answers in this post ([urllib2 not retrieving entire HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824069/urllib2-not-retrieving-entire-http-response)) which didn't work. I did use `urllib2.build_opener(proxy, urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)).open(url)` instead of`urllib2.urlopen(url)` for proxy and cookies, not sure if that made a difference.

The html that is returned seems to randomly cut off at line 803 of the source code which has a total of 1634 lines.

Is there a way to get all the html code?

Comment: I'm guessing your first suspicion was correct, and the page is dynamically generated. Instead of Firefox with disabled Javascript, try `curl` or `wget`. Do you still get the whole page?

Comment: Hmmm...yer I guess it was the javacript...but why would Firefox display it correctly with JS disabled?